# Converting HTML form into CSHTML Format

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET and I'm converting Java EE Project to ASP.NET MVC 4 , for that I have to convert HTML form view to CSHTML format

Here the HTML Code for the form:

```
<div id="hec-login">
<div id="login-tag-line" class="tag32">Higher Education Council Login</div>
<div id="ver-line">&nbsp; 
</div>


<div id="login-form-area">
<div class="login-username"> <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="validateHecUser_username" class="select" style="width:200px; float:left; height:42px;" placeholder="User Name">
</div>
</div>

<div id="login-form-area">
<div class="login-username"> <input type="password" name="password" id="validateHecUser_password" class="select" placeholder="Password">
</div>
</div>


<div id="login-botton">
<div class="login-username"><input type="image" alt="" src="~/Images/login.png" id="validateHecUser;jsessionid=60115189D49A29E0654E8315DA058D60_submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
</div>

</div>
```

up-to below level I tried to get the exact view in CSHTML,

CSHTML Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>

    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</fieldset>
```

I wish I can find any resource or way to proceed to get the exact HTML view in CSHTML Format

Comment: SOrry, But are you looking for any 3party tool or api which can convert your html pages into cshtml files ?

Comment: I just want to configure the fields to send the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try with this one ,

insert the code snippet of form text input areas within  `@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))`

just like below ,

```
      <div id="hec-login">
    <div id="login-tag-line" class="tag32">Higher Education Council & Higher Education Institute Login</div>
    <div id="ver-line">&nbsp; 
    </div>


    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <div id="login-form-area">
    <div class="login-username"> <input type="text" value="" name="UserName"  id="validateHecUser_username" class="select" style="width:200px; float:left; height:42px;" placeholder="User Name" >

    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="login-form-area">
    <div class="login-username"> <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="validateHecUser_password" class="select" placeholder="Password" >

    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="login-botton">
    <div class="login-username"><input type="image" alt="" src="~/Images/login.png" id="validateHecUser;jsessionid=60115189D49A29E0654E8315DA058D60_submit" name="submit" value="Log in">

    </div>

    </div>


   }   
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I would like you to look at [Microsoft virtual academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start) first. you can find all that you need here. From the code i understand that you are using Razor syntax which is great because you will get all the help in the link provided

Answer (score 0):

here is what I understood. Let me know if you need further information

1. You have converted your html page into cshtml view in mvc 4 application. That is fine. But you need to have a view model as you see you are using those model properties in your view.

   ```
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
   ```

So you need to create a model class and add it on top of view to access its properties.
example

```
@model  LoginViewModel
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<form>
<legend>Log in Form</legend>
<ol>
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    </li>

</ol>
<input type="button" id="login-button" value="Log in" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Login")'" />
</form>
```

Now you see that you have a login button with id = login-button.

You can use divs instead of ul li. They work here same way as they do in html pages that you used previously. That depends on your requirement completely.
This is how your model and its properties are defined. Note the data annotations. [Required]

```
namespace Models
{
    public class LoginViewModel
    {
          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Username")]
          public string UserName { get; set; }
          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Password")]
          public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You have to create a controller for Login

```
namespace Controllers
{
    public class LoginController
    {
         [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
         public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginModel)
         {
            //-- Your logic here.
         }
    }
}
```

To begin with you can follow this.
I hope this helps